# Guess correct column storage mode from data.frame of strings

Tags: r

Given a `data.frame` containing columns of only strings (no factors), some of which should remain strings, some of which are integers, and some of which are doubles, how can I guess the most appropriate storage mode to which to convert the strings?

```
fixDf <- data.frame(isChar=c("A", "B", "C"), 
  isDouble=c("0.01", "0.02", "0.03"), 
  isInteger=c("1", "2", "3"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to determine that the following needs to be done, and then to do it:

```
mode(fixDf[, "isDouble"]) <- "double"
mode(fixDf[, "isInteger"]) <- "integer"
```

Ideally, where errors are encountered a function to handle this would leave the data in its string form.

Comment: A couple of regexes (one for integers and one for doubles) would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: I would try to convert the column, and count the NAs produced...

Comment: Try just `type.convert(fixDf)`, credit [CephBirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76621708/6574038).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use `colwise` from the `plyr` package and the `type.convert` function.

```
library(plyr)
foo = colwise(type.convert)(fixDf)

str(foo)


'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ isChar   : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ isDouble : num  0.01 0.02 0.03
 $ isInteger: int  1 2 3
```

Or using base R:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(fixDf, type.convert))
```

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to `type.convert()`, which I believe is also exactly what the OP asked...

Comment: I like the base R approach.  However, to avoid the default creation of factors and leave character strings as character strings I found that you need to add this: `as.data.frame(lapply(fixDf, function(x) type.convert(x, as.is=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: The `as.is` argument to `type.convert` will not convert to factor.

Answer (score 7):

[`type_convert`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/type_convert.html) from **readr** does exactly what you want, operating on an entire data frame. It handles logical, numeric (integer and double), strings, and dates/times well, without coercing to factor.

```
type_convert(fixDf)
```

To parse columns individually, use [`parse_guess`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_guess.html).

Comment: This looks like it does the same thing as `type.convert` in utils.

Comment: I think `type.convert` only operates on a single column? I don't remember

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
foo <- read.table(text=capture.output(fixDf))
str(foo)
# 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ isChar   : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
#  $ isDouble : num  0.01 0.02 0.03
#  $ isInteger: int  1 2 3
```

Comment: With `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` that would be better than it already appears.

Comment: OP's aware of the option, so I left it out out of laziness. You're right, though, that's probably what he's looking for.

Answer (score 2):

With R versions >= 4.0.0, you can now just use base R's `type.convert()` directly without any `apply` and with defaulting to NOT convert strings to factors:

```
type.convert(fixDf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and the `magrittr` pipeline paradigm,

```
library(dplyr)

fixDf <- fixDf %>% 
  mutate_each(
    funs(
      type.convert(as.character(.), as.is = TRUE, numerals = "warn.loss")
    )
  )
```

In your case, the `as.character` coercion function is not needed, but it is good practice to include just in case you don't realize one or more of your columns is not a character variable -- `type.convert` requires character variables as input.

`as.is = TRUE` prevents coercion from character to factor, and `numerals = warn.loss` warns when converting a variable to `double` would cause the original value to lose accuracy (i.e., lose decimal places that are significant within the context of your analysis).